# Iterate through subdirectories with os.walk in particular order

Tags: python-3.x, os.walk

I'm trying to iterate through subdirectories of a top directory.
For each subdir I want to walk down into it's subdirectories and then walk down into the files of the subdir.

I've seen posts about os.walk but after spending a couple of morning train rides toying with it I haven't been able to come up with the solution.

I've checked the python documentation for os.walk and it has not helped me.

For a clarification, here is the directory structure:

```
topdir
   -> dirLesson1
          -> dirLanguageA
                 -> file1
                 -> file2
          -> dirLanguageB
                 -> file1
                 -> file2
   -> dirLesson2
          -> dirLanguageA
                 -> file1
                 -> file2
          -> dirLanguageB
                 -> file1
                 -> file2
```

And here is the pseudo code:

```
   for dirLesson in topdir
          # do something with dirLesson
          for dirLanguage in dirLesson
                 # do something with dirLanguage
                 for file in dirLanguage
                        #do something with file
```

I'm new to Python, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

def getSubDirs(dir):
    return [os.path.join(dir,name) for name in os.listdir(dir)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, name))]

def getSubFiles(dir):
    return [os.path.join(dir,name) for name in os.listdir(dir)
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, name))]


indir = "/topdir"
subDirArr = []
subSubDirArr = []
subSubFileArr = []

subDirArr.extend(getSubDirs(indir))

for dir in subDirArr:
    subSubDirArr.extend(getSubDirs(dir))

for dir in subSubDirArr:
    subSubFileArr.extend(getSubFiles(dir))

print "Here i am doing operation on level1 dirs"    
for dir in subDirArr:
    print os.path.basename(dir)

print "Here i am doing operation on level2 dirs"    
for dir in subSubDirArr:
        print os.path.basename(dir)

print "Here i am doing operation on level3 files"
for file in subSubFileArr:
        print os.path.basename(file)
```